# Can any higher order component in React be applied as decorator?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Can I use any higher order component in React be applied as decorator?
Or they need to be rewritten?

Comment: if you have `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`, then you can use them as decorators because that basically wraps like ```HOC(function())``` you can read more about it here https://medium.com/@mappmechanic/react-utility-higher-order-components-as-decorators-tc39-stage-2-9e9f3a17688a